# how to check network card bonding speed in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: networking, 10.04, network-manager

I have Ubuntu 10.04  install DELL R710 server

I have configured the network bonding using the below steps

```
sudo apt-get install ifenslave
-------------------------------------------
vi /etc/network/interfaces
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet manual
   bond-master bond0
 auto eth1
 iface eth1 inet manual
   bond-master bond0
 auto bond0
 iface bond0 inet static
   address 172.24.1.10
   gateway 172.24.1.1
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   dns-nameservers 172.24.1.50
   dns-search xxx.xxx
   bond-mode balance-rr
   bond-miimon 100
   bond-lacp-rate 1
   bond-slaves none
----------------------------------------------------------
cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.5.0 (November 4, 2008)
Bonding Mode: load balancing (round-robin)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0
Slave Interface: eth0
MII Status: up
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Slave Interface: eth1
MII Status: up
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:yy
----------------------------------------------------------------
 **its not showing the bonding speed .**
---------------------------------------------------------
ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised link modes:  Not reported
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: Unknown
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: g
        Link detected: yes
 ethtool eth1
Settings for eth1:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised link modes:  Not reported
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: Unknown
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: g
        Link detected: yes
```

both network card speed is 1000MBPS.  How do I check the bond0 network speed.

Answer (score 0):

It's completely related to your bonding strategy..
that speed only shows the maximum connection speed between network adapters in local network.and most of the time it's not true!

Based on **bond-mode** you selected within */etc/network/interfaces* and description of **balance-rr** in ubuntu documents ,this mode is for **Transmit packets in sequential order from the first available slave through the last. This mode provides load balancing and fault tolerance**. 
It depends on the way you request packets and accessibility of each interface or route to that point in network.take a look at this [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding) .